# API request for LinkedIn user data always returns 401

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am building back-end(API) of mobile application on asp.net core. Using swagger for visualization of API calls and so on. Currently I am creating external authentications, I have some problems with LinkedIn.

The structure of application is simple, mobile side gets LinkedIn user's Access Token and sends it to me with API request, I have to request user data from LinkedIn by received Access Token, register or login him/her and return response to mobile side.

There is the code below, and commented links where I tried to send requests.

```
    public async Task<IResponse<LinkedInAuthenticationResponse>> LinkedInAuthentication(string accessToken)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-li-format", "json");
            var oauthUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people";

            // https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
            // https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)

            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(oauthUrl).Result;
            string responseContent = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return Ok(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleAuthenticationResponse>(responseContent));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that LinkedIn doesn't provide exact link where API call should be send, I had to try several of them but **the response is always 401.**

My Access Token is valid, this can not be problem. I have used almost same code for Facebook and Google and they work perfectly.

Any one can provide link which works for API calls ?

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the `asp.net` framework but with the endpoint, you are using. Since v1 of the LinkedIn API has been deprecated, you need to change your endpoint as for [this link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-2-request-an-authorization-code)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with the `asp.net` framework but with the endpoint, you are using. Since v1 of the LinkedIn API has been deprecated, you need to change your endpoint as for [this link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-2-request-an-authorization-code)